# Derived property value is not persistent when assigning it to an object value in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, google-maps, vuejs3, capacitor

I am trying to create an object to use in the Ionic Capacitor Google Maps API to configure the map at it's creation. Unfortunately, the value of the ref I use is not persistent and reverts to its default value. I have been trying to solve this issue for days with no success. Any help in showing how to make this work would be much appreciated. My code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { Geolocation } from "@capacitor/geolocation";

const currPos = ref<any | null>(null);
const lat = ref<number>(1);
const lng = ref<number>(2);

const getLocation = async () => {
  console.log("got getLocation event");
  currPos.value = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 20000,
  });
  lat.value = currPos.value.coords.latitude;
  lng.value = currPos.value.coords.longitude;
};

const centerLat = computed(() => (lat.value ? lat.value : 3));

const mapConfig = {
  center: {
    // The initial position to be rendered by the map
    // lat: 32.78025, // this works
    // lng: -117.19335, // this works
    lat: centerLat.value as number, // not working, is 1
    lng: lng.value as number, // not working, is 2
  },
  zoom: 10,
};

const logLocData = () => {
  console.log("Latitude", lat.value); // shows correct number for lat
  console.log("Longitude", lng.value); // shows correct number for lng
  console.log("Center Latitude", centerLat.value); // shows correct number for centerLat
  console.log("MapCofig", mapConfig); // wrong, shows center and 1 for lat and 2 for lng
  console.log("MapCofig Latitude", mapConfig.center.lat); // wrong, shows 1 for lat
  console.log("MapCofig Longitude", mapConfig.center.lng); // wrong, shows 2 for lng
};

onMounted(() => {
  console.log("mounted");
  getLocation();
});
</script>
```

Console log:

```
mounted
got getLocation event
Latitude 32.7822162
Longitude -117.1852825
Center Latitude 32.7822162
MapCofig {center: {…}, zoom: 10}
MapCofig Latitude 1
MapCofig Longitude 2
```

Comment: Sorry, the log does not format correctly.

I've tried everything I could, too much to document here. I'm expecting the mapConfig lat/lng values to be set to the current position values I get from the Geolocation API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapConfig` is not reactive.

With minimal changes, this should work:

```
mapConfig = computed(() => ({
  center: {
    lat: centerLat.value,
    lng: lng.value
  },
  zoom: 10,
}))
```

---

But I would personally go with this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, toRefs, onMounted, reactive } from "vue"

type State = {
  lat: number
  lng: number
  centerLat: number
  mapConfig: {
    center: {
      lat: number
      lng: number
    }
    zoom: number
  }
  currPos: {
    coords: {
      latitude: number
      longitude: number
    }
  } | null
}
const state: State = reactive({
  currPos: null,
  lat: computed(() => state.currPos?.coords.latitude || 1),
  lng: computed(() => state.currPos?.coords.longitude || 2),
  centerLat: computed(() => state.lat || 3),
  mapConfig: computed(() => ({
    center: {
      lat: state.centerLat,
      lng: state.lng
    },
    zoom: 10
  }))
})
const getLocation = async () => {
  state.currPos = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 20000
  })
}
const initMap() {
  // init map here...
}
onMounted(() => getLocation().then(initMap))

// expose stuff to template, if you don't want the `state.` prefix:
const { lat, lng, mapConfig } = toRefs(state)
</script>
```

I find it cleaner and easier to work with/follow (I'm guessing you'll be expanding it).

Comment: The last line in mapConfig should be })); but yes! this works!  I may change to your suggested code once I have done more testing and I understand everything better.

Comment: Yep, missed a closing bracket. Updated!

Comment: I implemented your State approach and it also works.  Unfortunately, the map is still coming up centered on 0, 0 even though the console log shows correct lat and lng values (also mapConfig looks good).  It does this with my original approach too.  I'm wondering if this may be a bug in the Capacitor Google Maps plugin.

Comment: I doubt the map is responsive. It probably has some method to ***set*** its center/zoom/pitch, etc... I don't know about yours, but mapbox, leaflet, open maps, all need a function called to change any param.

Comment: You are correct, this map also has functions to change map parameters.  My problem is with the initial default position the map centers on when first rendered.  This is hardcoded in all the Capacitor examples I've seen. The API from Google's website allows non-hardcoded values. In my app the zoom works correctly in both approaches. So I don't think this is a problem with mapConfig.  It's something related to the lat.value and state.lat being no hardcoded.

Comment: I'm guessing you instantiate the map before `lat` changes. Perhaps you should wait until `getLocation` returns? You could always `watch(() => ({ lat: state.lat, lng: state.lng }), () => { /* this triggers when lng or lat change in state */})`.

Comment: I must apologize, the map is not rendering to 0,0, when first created.  It is actually centering on the defaults set when the lat and lng were computed (1 and 2).  This implies that lat and lng are not set to the current geolocation when the map is created.  What is confusing is lat and lng are correct when logged to the console (a manual button click after the map is rendered).

Comment: Sounds like you should set `lng` and `lat` to `null` initially and only instantiate the map in `getLocation` after the assignment to `state.currPos`. That should instantiate the map with the correct `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: You are correct again.  I logged lat and lng directly before the map is created and they had not updated yet.  This is after getLocation was called, so I'm not sure the best way to wait.  BTW, I am using my original approach since I understand it better.  I will try using the State approach.

Comment: I need to see the code that instantiates the map to be able to help. If it's a template element which does all the magic, just place a `v-if="lng && lat"` on it. This will stop it from rendering (hence instantiating the map) until `lng` and `lat` have been populated. Assuming their default value is set to `null` (or `0`).

Comment: I'm setting the lat and lng values to the current location at the end of the getLocation function.  Immediately afterwards I get the mapRef (the container for the map in the template) and then create the map.  I did testing and the lat and lng are taking about 200ms to populate. All the later functions execute and complete before the lat and lng values are available so that is why the map centered in the wrong location.

Comment: *"Immediately afterwards I get the mapRef (...) and then create the mapRef"*. I don't see that code. Can you share it? I bet it runs before you think it does. Update the question if you need my help solving this. Read my previous comment carefully. It holds the key to solving your issue.

Comment: I was able to get the map to center with a function that waits until the lat and lng populate (and times out if they don't). The function does not work correctly but delays long enough to let the map center correctly.  I can share my code, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: My code is shared at: https://codepen.io/archesystems/pen/gOdoRMq.

I will post it here when I have enough reputation points. My code now works 100% after getting help from you.

Comment: @Essentia, I urge you to delete that pen or at least to modify it and remove your google maps api key from it. If you want to leave it for posterity, replace the key with `INSERT VALID API KEY HERE`

Comment: @Essentia, I never really understood why people use `codepen.io`. It's so restrictive. And it's ***exactly*** in cases like yours where it shows the most! Here's the same, in [`codesandbox.io`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/crazy-chebyshev-uwxwh2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue). Except in codesandbox it actually works  (once you insert a valid google maps api key, of course). I doubt codepen.io could run a ionic app. Side note: I simplified your mounted hook.

Comment: I was using Codepen to share my code and knew it would not actual work there. I don't have experience with online development websites and didn't know what else to do.  Thanks for the codesandbox.io suggestion, I'll use it in the future.  I have 43 years of professional hardware Electronics Engineering design experience and that's my strength.  Software is not.  I tested your simplified code and it works perfectly.  Thank you again, I have learned a lot and you've help me get past a brick wall!